# Unable to install Rust

Tags: installation, rust

I am trying to install Rust. However I'm unable to complete the installation due to this error:

```
E:\My Projects\solana>curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: On the [rustup page](https://rustup.rs/) there is a link dedicated to platforms different from Unix (i.e. Windows).

Comment: The instructions that you followed in [this page](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install) are for installing _Rustup in the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are attempting to use a unix shell program (`sh`) to execute a script downloaded from `curl` on a Windows-based machine. This is unlikely to work. Look at this link instead: https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was trying to do the same thig. Now i have downloaded and run rustup-init.exe on Windows. Thank you Nathaniel Ford.